# Creating a new project with leiningen in windows 7

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How do I create a new project in Windows 7 with leiningen as explained in the [tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md) (the tutorial is for unix).

Answer (score 3):

Leiningen will work very much the same in Windows and the tutorial is basically OS agnostic. You do want to be familiar with your Windows 7 CMD console. You can use the native CMD console,

http://vishnuvalentino.com/tips-and-trick/16-steps-tutorial-basic-command-prompt/

Though I recommend you download a third-party add-on to the console that will make the experience nicer. An example of that is Console2,

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

Advanced users might use different tools (http://www.petri.co.il/alternative-command-shells_for-windows.htm) but I recommend you start with the basics.

Comment: When you say that tutorial is OS agnostic, I am not sure I understand that. When I enter the commands from the tutorial into the cmd I get an erro: `C:\windows\system32>$ lein new app my-stuff
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` How do I translate this commant to windows?

Comment: @Zeynel Don't type the leading "$" -- that just indicates the command prompt.

Comment: @A. Webb Still does not work: `C:\windows\system32>lein new app my-stuff
The system cannot find the path specified.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Zeynel I can't say for certain, but looking at your prompt it seems you are trying to create a new project with the system32 folder as your current folder. Perhaps the OS is restricting the creation of files within its system critical folders. You should add lein to your path and try executing from a user directory instead.

Comment: Yes, I did this and I got the cmd working, thanks, but I get an that I posted to clojure forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/I6lRsd75om4